# Transform text in html span by id (created by javascript) to php variable to use in if condition

Tags: javascript, php, html

Can you please help me with the following issue. My file index.php includes another php file with javascript that on a click creates a text 'abcdf'

```
$('#clicked-item1').text(clicked_item.data('id'));
```

Then I can reproduce the text in index.php by

```
<?php 
$test = '<span id ="clicked-item1" ></span>'; 
echo $test; 
?>
```

Then, I need a condition like:

```
if ($test == 'abcdf') { ... }
```

However, the php condition does not work. Please advise what is wrong.

Comment: You post is rather unclear at the moment. Please reformulate and describe what you are expecting

Comment: You want to compare the span contents or id attribute?

Comment: I have edited my question to make it clear. I need to compare span text content with a predefined text 'abcdf'.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what are you trying with this, but...

$test is a STRING.

```
$test = '<span id ="clicked-item1"></span>';
```

So... `echo $test;` will ALWAYS print:

`<span id ="clicked-item1"></span>`.

Remember that PHP is SERVER-SIDE language.
And Javascript is CLIENT-SIDE.

Whenever you run your code, you are executing the PHP part first, and THEN the Javascript one. You can pass PHP variables to Javascript, but not the other way around.

You need to use Ajax [Post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)...

```
$('#clicked_item').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.post("index.php", {id: id}, function(result){
        //Show success message, or whatever.
    });
});
```

In index.php:

```
$id = $_POST['id']

if($id == "abcdf")
{
    //Do whatever you want.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for good advice. However, there is still something that leads to:  "Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.30-1\apache2\htdocs\...\index.php on line 109".  Line 109 is: $id = $_POST['id']. Your recommended Ajax Post was placed in file1.php that included in index.php:  include 'file1.php';

Comment: If index.php is what you run to see your HTML then you can't expect for a ID post to exists. (You cant make a post if the page is not even loaded).

Remember this flow... php -> javascript (here your "span" and click event) -> another php. Don't include one into another.
Or you can make a simple <form> post with index.php and post.php. Take a look at google for plenty of examples.

Comment: Thank you. I understand it, however I was confused why html span method works nicely to echo (print) right content even with included files, i.e. <span id ="clicked-item1"></span> prints 'abcdf', but it does not work with 'if'.

Comment: Well, im also confussed now. Im pretty sure that $test is an static value and will never return de content between <span></span>. You can't read the content inside HTML elements in PHP like that. Maybe you missed some block of code in your original question.

Comment: I think that I wrote everything in index.php about this issue. And   echo $test;   prints 'abcdf' but if I try   echo substr($test,1);   then it prints    span id ="clicked-item1"></span>,    i.e. the string itself without '<'. The last fact is in complete agreement with your thoughts, but nevertheless    echo $test;   works nicely and even    echo substr($test,0);   prints 'abcdf'.

Comment: Well... In that case (very peculiar) you can precede with a "(string)" to forcecast your variable. Something like $string = (string)$test; Now substr() or even your condition should work. Let me know, it's an interesting behavior.

Comment: $string = (string)$test; does not change anything. $string behaves exactly like $test, including substr(). One more interesting addition to the previous:  echo $test . $test; prints 'abcdf' only one time.